# Modifying date in ColdFusion

Tags: date, coldfusion

How can I adjust a date in coldfusion to get the next day at 1AM?

the date is taken from a database, and stored as a string. I'm thinking the way to do it is through `CreateDateTime` and filling it with the time and date using year,month,day + 1 etc.

I'm just worried that it won't work when the next day falls on the next month

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to get the day after the date that is stored in your database? If that is the case, grab the value from your database, check vs. `isDate()`, then continue as per Jason Dean's answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using DateAdd() you can always be sure that it will take the context of the current date into account. So if it is August 31 and you add one day it will correctly make the date Sept 1st. It will also properly switch the year if you did the same on Dec 31st.

```
<cfset nextDate = dateAdd("d", 1, now()) />
<cfset nextDateWithTime = createDateTime(year(nextDate), month(nextDate), day(nextDate), 1, 0, 0) />

<cfoutput>#nextDateWithTime#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the date is something which CF recognizes as a date, and contains date only, without time, you could do something like:

```
<cfscript>
function tomorrowOneAM(date) {
    var resultValue = DateAdd("d",1,date);
    resultValue = DateAdd("h",1,resultValue);
    return resultValue;
}

</cfscript>
```

Comment: it is using a time component as-well, but I suppose I could use dateformat to get the date only

Comment: Just happen to have that laying around:

function dayOnly(datetime) {
 var year=year(datetime);
 var month=month(datetime);
 var day=day(datetime);
 return CreateDateTime(year,month,day,0,0,0);
}